# Python Requests Get not Working

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a simple Get request I'd like to make using Python's Request library.

```
import requests
HEADERS = {'user-agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5)'
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
                          'Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36'),
                          'referer': 'http://stats.nba.com/scores/'}
url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playbyplayv2?EndPeriod=10&EndRange=55800&GameID=0021500281&RangeType=2&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, headers=HEADERS)
```

However, when I make the `requests.get` call, I get the error `requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='stats.nba.com', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=5)`. But I am able to copy/paste that url into my browser and view the resulting JSON. Why is requests not able to get the result?

Comment: When concatenating the strings by `('AAA' 'BBB')` you get `AAABBB` not `AAA BBB` so I guess you are missing a few spaces in your user-agent header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `HEADERS` format is wrong. I tried with this code and it worked without any issues:

```
import requests
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.87 Safari/537.36',
}
url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playbyplayv2?EndPeriod=10&EndRange=55800&GameID=0021500281&RangeType=2&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StartPeriod=1&StartRange=0'
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5, headers=HEADERS)
print(response.text)
```